# Get key names from key value pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Rails 4 on Ruby 2.0

I'm trying to populate a select tag with a key value pair array I have setup in my model. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to grab the key. Here is what I have so far:

**Model**

```
class Store
    Colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'pink', 'purple', 'lime', 'magenta', 'teal']
    SearchParams = {'isbn' => 'ISBN', 'intitle' => 'Title', 'inauthor' => 'Author', 'inpublisher' => 'Publisher', 'subject' => 'Subject', 'lccn' => 'LCCN', 'oclc' => 'OCLC'}
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
    @search_params = Store::SearchParams.map { |param| [param, param.key] }
end
```

note: I am aware that `.key` does not exist - I added that hoping it would better communicate what I am trying to do.

**View**

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%= select_tag :param_name, @search_params, prompt: 'choose' %>
<% end %>
```

I would like the value of each `<option>` to be the key, and for the user to see the value. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally use [`options_for_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) to provide the options for [`select_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag). Conveniently, you can hand a Hash to `options_for_select` and it will do the right thing:

> **options_for_select(container, selected = nil)**
>
> Accepts a container (hash, array, enumerable, your type) and returns a string of option tags. [...]

The problem is that `options_for_select` wants the Hash's keys to be what the human sees and the values to be the `value` attributes for the `<option>`s. Your Hash is backwards but you can use [`Hash#invert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-invert) to flip the keys and values around:

> **invert → new_hash**
>
> Returns a new hash created by using `hsh`’s values as keys, and the keys as values.

So you could just do this in your controller:

```
@search_params = Store::SearchParams.invert
```

and then this in the ERB:

```
<%= select_tag :param_name, options_for_select(@search_params), prompt: 'choose' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this itself will work

def index
    @search_params = Store::SearchParams.to_a 
    //it will return the array you want, but the values will be [[key1,value1],[key2,value2]]
    // if you want to reverse itm then Store::SearchParams.to_a.collect{|arr| arr.reverse} will give that
end

Answer (score 1):

That will do it:

```
def index
  @search_params = Store::SearchParams.map { |key, val| [val, key] }
end
```

---

**UPD**: consider also `Hash#invert` (thanks to @mu is too short)